# Laravel - Check if $id is exist in the URL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How to check if $id is exist in the URL before proceeding further?

In the route I have:

```
Route::get('list', 'ListController@showList');
Route::get('list/detail/{id}', 'ListController@showListDetail');
```

and in the controller file I have:

```
   public function showListDetail($id = null)
    {

        if ($id == null)  {
            return Redirect::to("/");
        }

        echo "Test - Found ID: $id";
    }
```

In the browser, when I enter: `http://project.dev/list/detail` I get an error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

However, when I tried `http://project.dev/list/detail/123` it work fine.

Comment: In addition to the good answers you have thus far, you could always explicitly declare a route for `list/detail` that redirects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make the `id`-parameter optional by setting up your route like that:

```
Route::get('list/detail/{id?}', 'ListController@showListDetail');
```

see the docs on [route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters) for further details

Comment: Thank you, that work! Would you use `if ($id == null)` to check?

Comment: But consider @ceejayoz comment. since i dont know what exactly you are trying to achieve with your routes, this migth be an alternative. I am a big fan of restful_routing using `Route::resource(..)`. This is one of the cleanest ways to route IMO

Answer (score 1):

Change your route to the following, this makes ID optional:

```
Route::get('list/detail/{id?}', 'ListController@showListDetail');
```